# Will the TMC2130 V3.0 stepper driver work with the Ramps 1.6 Plus board?

Tags: stepper-driver, skr-v1.3, bigtreetech, ramps-1.6, tmc2130

I want to buy the board [Ramps 1.6 Plus](https://www.hta3d.com/en/ramps-1-6-plus-compatible-with-spi-compatible-with-tmc2130). The description in the link says that is compatible with the driver TMC2130, but I found that there are two versions soldered in SPI mode.

- [BIGTREETECH TMC2130 V3.0](https://www.hta3d.com/en/tmc2130-welded-for-spi-stepper-motor-controller-silent-driver). Where the diagnosis pins are soldered as well
- [TMC2130 V?](https://www.hta3d.com/en/tmc2130-sb-spi-version-stepper-motor-driver-carrier-low-noise-driver). In this other product those pins are not soldered and I believe it will fit in the board

[image: comparison]

As you can see in the image other boards like the SKR 1.3 have some socket to plug in the diagnosis pins. But I don't see something similar in the Ramps 1.6, which has male pins instead.

- Should I remove those pins in order to plug the driver? Or is there a better way to proceed?
- I don't really know what the diagnosis pins do, are they really necessary? Should I buy the second option without those pins soldered to avoid problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found that I can use a DuPont cable to connect the diag1 pin to the right endstop

[image]

There is also a beta functionality in the Marlin firmware I haven't tried: Just uncommenting `SPI_ENDSTOPS` definition

```
    * SPI_ENDSTOPS  *** Beta feature! *** TMC2130 Only ***
    * Poll the driver through SPI to determine load when homing.
    * Removes the need for a wire from DIAG1 to an endstop pin.
    *
    * IMPROVE_HOMING_RELIABILITY tunes acceleration and jerk when
    * homing and adds a guard period for endstop triggering.
*/
#define SENSORLESS_HOMING // StallGuard capable drivers only

#if EITHER(SENSORLESS_HOMING, SENSORLESS_PROBING)
    // TMC2209: 0...255. TMC2130: -64...63
    #define X_STALL_SENSITIVITY  8
    #define X2_STALL_SENSITIVITY X_STALL_SENSITIVITY
    #define Y_STALL_SENSITIVITY  8
    //#define Z_STALL_SENSITIVITY  8
    //#define SPI_ENDSTOPS              // TMC2130 only
    //#define IMPROVE_HOMING_RELIABILITY
#endif
```